# How to read filenames from the download directory on android 10 and higher?

Tags: android, api, download

How to read filenames from the download directory on android 10 and higher?
After filtering the names I want to let users select from this list to open
the file.

On Android versions 8 (API 28) the FILE api is quite simple to use.
Filenames are simple to read with the method DirListOld. With these names
I can read the content of the files.

I tried to make a method to do the same on Android 10 (API 30) and higher.
But documentation is not very clear. I did some experimenting with
MediaStore methods, but I could not get the filenames only got directory
names on external storage.
How to filter the results is not very well documented and examples of the
MediaStore.Downlaods are totally absent.
My experiment is shown in method DirListNew.

Also I had to ask for a permission for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Without this
permission even DirListNew results in an empty string. As I read in several
comments Google-Play is not generous in giving this permission. Why not
special permission for only downloaded files. I don't have to read all external
files.
I don't understand why Google-Android developers made such a mess for retrieving
simple downloaded files.

```
public String DirListOld()
{
    String sName;
    File oDownloadDir;
    String sDownloadDir;
    StringBuilder dirContent = new StringBuilder();

    oDownloadDir = this.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    try {
        sDownloadDir = oDownloadDir.getName();
        if (!sDownloadDir.equals("") )
        {
            for (File f : Objects.requireNonNull(oDownloadDir.listFiles()))
            {
                if (f.isFile())
                {
                    sName = f.getName();
                    dirContent.append(sName);
                    dirContent.append("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dirContent.toString();
} // DirListOld

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
public String DirListNew()
{
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextMultiLine2);
    StringBuilder dirContent = new StringBuilder();
    String[] projection = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Downloads.DATA
    };
    String selection = null; 
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = null;

    Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder
    );
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        //iterate over rows
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            //iterate over the columns
            for(int j = 0; j < cursor.getColumnNames().length; j++){
                //append the column value to the string builder and delimit by \n
                dirContent.append(cursor.getString(j));
                dirContent.append("\n");
            }
            //add a new line carriage return
            dirContent.append("\n");
            //move to the next row
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        //close the cursor
        cursor.close();
    }
    return dirContent.toString();
} // DirListNew
```

Comment: On an Android 10 device you can use the same code if you have requestLegacyExternalStoraage="true" in application tag of manifest file.

Comment: Hmmm.. same code? `oDownloadDir = this.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`That is not THE Download dir.
  `

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong versie of DirLIstOld in that function I used getExternalStoragePublicDirectory which is depricated. I was looking for alternative. So I could use the same code for old and new API's.
Until now I only found:
/storage/emulated/0/Download that worked for all API's. But is an ugly solution.